# Is there anything like ICommand in Qt/QML?

Tags: qt, validation, qml

To achieve the same functionality I've in my WPF application, here I've created a `Q_INVOKABLE` named `isNewPlotValid` and call it whenever the content of my fields change:

```
ColumnLayout{
    LineField{
        label: "Name"
        text: addContext.newPlot.name
        onTextChanged: {
            addContext.newPlot.name = text
            button.isEnabled = addContext.isNewPlotValid()
        }
    }
    AreaField{
        label: "Address"
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        text: addContext.newPlot.description
        onTextChanged: {
            addContext.newPlot.description = text
            button.isEnabled = addContext.isNewPlotValid()
        }
    }
    PathButton{
        id: button
        pathData: C.addIcon
        onClicked: addContext.addNewPlot()
    }
}
```

It does what I wanted it to do BUT I've to have `button.isEnabled = addContext.isNewPlotValid()` in every field! Is there any shortcut?

**EDIT**

In the `Model` folder of my project I've ony header files that define data structure (Q_PROPERTY) like this:

```
class Plot : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Property(int, id)
    Property(QString, name)
    Property(QString, description)
};
```

nothing more for any type of `Model` except `enum` and the `Property` macro creates all necessary Q stuffs for the `Model` with this:

```
#define Property(QType, name) \
    Q_PROPERTY(QType name READ name WRITE set##name NOTIFY name##Changed) \
    public: \
        QType& name() {return m_##name;} \
        void set##name(QType value){if(m_##name != value){m_##name = value; emit name##Changed();}} \
        Q_SIGNAL void name##Changed(); \
    private: \
        QType m_##name;
```

All my `ViewModels` are in a separate folder called `ViewModel`. I've one ViewModel named `AddVM` and it's a `Property` of Type `Plot*`:

```
class AddVM : public QObject
{
    ...
    Property(Plot*, newPlot)
    ...
};
```

Now this will notify the UI only when the pointer is changed. So do I have to create another `slot` that does this:

```
void AddVM::onPlotChanged()
{
    emit newPlotChanged();
}
```

and connect `newPlot`'s nameChanged and descriptionChanged signal with that `onPlotChanged` slot? I've tried to connect both this way:

```
QObject::connect(m_newPlot, &AddVM::m_newPlot->nameChanged, this, &AddVM::onPlotChanged);
QObject::connect(m_newPlot, &AddVM::m_newPlot->descriptionChanged, this, &AddVM::onPlotChanged);
```

BUT the second argument, `&AddVM::m_newPlot->nameChanged` and  `&AddVM::m_newPlot->descriptionChanged`, on both lines says:

> cannot create a non-constant pointer to member function.

**EDIT**

So the solution is to have these in `AddVM`:

```
class AddVM : public QObject
{
    Property(Plot*, newPlot)
    Property(bool, isNewPlotValid)

private:
    bool hasMatch(QString& text);
    void hookupSignalAndSlots();

private slots:
    void onPlotChanged();
};
```

these in `cpp`:

```
bool AddVM::hasMatch(QString &text)
{
    foreach(auto x, mvm->plots())
        if(x->name() == text) return true;
    return false;
}

void AddVM::hookupSignalAndSlots()
{
    QObject::connect(m_newPlot, &Plot::nameChanged, this, &AddVM::onPlotChanged);
    QObject::connect(m_newPlot, &Plot::descriptionChanged, this, &AddVM::onPlotChanged);
}

void AddVM::onPlotChanged()
{
    if(!newPlot()->name().isEmpty() && !newPlot()->description().isEmpty() && !hasMatch(newPlot()->name()))
        setisNewPlotValid(true);
    else setisNewPlotValid(false);
}
```

and these in the `qml`:

```
ColumnLayout{
    LineField{
        label: "Name"
        text: addContext.newPlot.name
        onTextChanged: addContext.newPlot.name = text
    }
    AreaField{
        label: "Address"
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        text: addContext.newPlot.description
        onTextChanged: addContext.newPlot.description = text
    }
    PathButton{
        pathData: C.addIcon
        toolTip: "insert into database"
        onClicked: addContext.addNewPlot()
        isEnabled: addContext.isNewPlotValid
    }
}
```

works as expected.

Comment: You need to write it like this: `QObject::connect(m_newPlot, &AddVM::nameChanged, this, &AddVM::onPlotChanged);`

Comment: @Amfasis, `AddVM` doesn't have the definition for `nameChanged` signal, it's created in the `Plot` header with the help of that macro. If I do that on `AddVM`, it says `no member named 'nameChanged' in 'AddVM'`.

Comment: Oh sorry ;-) another try: `QObject::connect(m_newPlot, &Plot::nameChanged, this, &AddVM::onPlotChanged);`

Comment: @Amfasis, this one is successful! For a property with 8/9 fields, it'd be a mess.

Comment: @Amfasis, you could update your answer if you wish, I've accepted it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert that `Q_INVOKABLE` to a property which can `NOTIFY`, so that the QML Engine knows the property changed, then you can bind that property to the `enabled` property of either each button individually or to the whole `ColumnLayout` at once.

Add to your "addContext" class:

```
Q_PROPERTY(bool isNewPlotValid READ isNewPlotValid NOTIFY isNewPlotValidChanged)

//add signal:
signals:
    void isNewPlotValidChanged();
```

The tricky part might be to signal on the correct spots, but that's unclear from the provided code. If you have a lot of conditions, you can add multiple `emit isNewPlotValidChanged();` calls on the places where these conditions change. The QML engine will always re-read the value by calling `isNewPlotValid()` and apply the new value (which can thus still be the same).

Then you have to adjust your QML to:

```
ColumnLayout{
    //enabled: addContext.isNewPlotValid

    LineField{
        label: "Name"
        text: addContext.newPlot.name
        onTextChanged: {
            addContext.newPlot.name = text
        }
    }
    AreaField{
        label: "Address"
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        text: addContext.newPlot.description
        onTextChanged: {
            addContext.newPlot.description = text
        }
    }
    PathButton{
        id: button
        pathData: C.addIcon
        enabled: addContext.isNewPlotValid
        onClicked: addContext.addNewPlot()
    }
}
```

Enabling the whole `ColumnLayout` has the advantage that the input field also get disabled, but it depends on your situation.

Comment: I've edited the post to add more info, have a look at the edit part please.